# How to create data frame from np.array inside a for loop in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

all_cases= np.array([])
for i in range(1, 4):
    subSoil_array= [i, 2*i, 3*i]
    case_i=np.append(subSoil_array, 100*i) 
    print(case_i)
    #print (all_cases)
```

I need to create a data frame (3 rows- 4 columns) from the above for loop. The first row should be
1  2  3  100
and the last one:
3  6  9  300

I have tried some lines. No luck. Any advice, please?

Comment: What are you hoping to make the frame from?  `all_cases`?  That starts as a (0,) shape array, and stays that way; nothing in your loop changes that.  You make `case_i` in the loop, but don't save it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) you wouldn't use a loop but vectorial code with broadcasting.

In your case:

```
arr = np.arange(1, 4)[:,None]*np.array([1, 2, 3, 100])
```

Output:

```
array([[  1,   2,   3, 100],
       [  2,   4,   6, 200],
       [  3,   6,   9, 300]])
```

##### with a loop

Use a list to collect the values and [`vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
l = []
for i in range(1, 4):
    subSoil_array= [i, 2*i, 3*i]
    l.append(np.r_[subSoil_array, 100*i]) 

all_cases = np.vstack(l)
```

Output:

```
array([[  1,   2,   3, 100],
       [  2,   4,   6, 200],
       [  3,   6,   9, 300]])
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but the values I put here are just "examples". I have to use a for loop, in which the four columns of each "case" are calculated from some internal functions.  For example, in each raw, the first three entries are "soil properties," and the fourth is " soil strength." I want to create a data frame for three different soil cases....

Comment: OK, see update. Don't `append` to an array in a loop this is highly inefficient (quadratic complexity). Instead collect in a list and `vstack`